# How to set a cookie in nginx with specific path fragment as a value?

Tags: nginx

I need to redirect /referral/ID and /referral/ID/ urls (with or without trailing slash) to the root url, but store the ID value in a cookie. I'm trying to do it with the following location section, but this doesn't work.

```
location /referral {
    if ($request_uri ~ "/referral/(.*)(?\/)(.*)") {
        add_header Set-Cookie "referral-id=$1;Max-Age=100000";
    }

    rewrite ^ / permanent;
}
```

How can I achieve it with nginx?

Comment: If you already saw my answer please note that I'm slightly optimized it just now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the solutions:

```
http {

    ...

    map $id $ref_id {
        ~. "referral=$id;Path=/;Max-Age=100000"; # any non-empty value
        # otherwise result of map translation would be an empty string
    }

    server {

        ...

        location ~ ^/referral(?:/(?<id>[^/]+))? {
            add_header Set-Cookie $ref_id;
            return 301 /;
        }

    }

}
```

If `$id` variable is empty or null, result of `$id` to `$ref_id` translation will be an empty string, and nginx would not set `Set-Cookie` (or any other HTTP header when an empty value passed as parameter **value** of `add_header` directive) at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I like it very much because of usage of map.
Unfortunately, I could not get this to work. When I open a page "/referral/ID", I can saw in Chrome DevTools that cookie has been set, but it dissapear almost instantly and I don't know why.

Comment: @Digger2000 I tested this config with `curl`. Now I did some research on this. The reason is very simple. Since we didn't explicitly set the cookie path, Chrome assumes that it is `/referral`. After being redirected to the root page the cookie disappears from DevTools (since you're not on the `/referral` page anymore), but you can see the cookie was set on the `chrome://settings/cookies/detail?site=example.com` page (replace `example.com` with your actual domain). The fix for this is quite simple, just add the root path to your cookie: `~. "referral=$id;Path=/;Max-Age=100000";`.