# Why is this cookie not preserved across requests?

Tags: php, symfony, cookies, setcookie, symfony5

I want to add a cookie with a value once the user was logged in Symfony, a cookie that was saved during all requests for the current session and check if that cookie exists in nginx, if so the file will be shown.

The cookie was created and sent but it is valid only for one request and it is not sent along all new requests. I am adding new cookie in this way:

```
$response = new Response();
$time = time() + (3600 * 24 * 7);
$response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie("nametest", "test", $time, "/"));
$response->sendHeaders();
```

EDIT: Adding path as "/" sends the cookie across all requests. Now the last step is to verify the cookie in nginx. I am using the following nginx config:

```
location /assets/users/images/ {
    if ($cookie_nametest !~* "test") {
       return 301 https://example_domain.com/login;
    }
}
```

Comment: Still no luck? :) I remember one of my old answers, maybe it will help. I don't see any other errors in your code or your nginx [config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67963136/checking-nginx-cookies-data-does-not-work-as-expected).

Comment: Not yet, but I think that your answer has the key to my issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the possible reasons for this can be that you didn't specify your cookie path. For example, if this cookie is being set on the login page `https://example.com/login`, it will be sent from user browser to server for URIs starting with `/login` and not any else. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60005037/7121513) is an example of this behavior (initially the needed cookie was set with `/referral` path and was invisible from the root URI, read both answer and comments). Following [this](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-3-cookie-improvements#creating-cookies-with-strings) example looks like you should use something like

```
$response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie("name_test", "test", $time, "/"));
```

However disadvantage of this approach is that your "secret" cookie name and value are hard-coded within the nginx config. Since your original question title was **How to block direct file access for non authenticated users?** I can suggest you a completely different solution using the `X-Accel-Redirect` response header. The idea is that you can check if the user is logged in at the backend and then respond with the right path to the protected file. [Here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/x-accel/#x-accel-redirect) is the official documentation and [here](https://kovyrin.net/2006/11/01/nginx-x-accel-redirect-php-rails/) is an example. Note the `internal` keyword inside the protected `location` block.

Comment: Checking my code again I think that you are right, I did not include the path for the cookie and probably is applied only to the current url. And yes, the value of the cookie being hardcoded is not the best but I want to check if I can encrypt it and decode in nginx. X-Accel-Redirect sounds good! I am going to check it, thanks for taking the time to give your answer :)

Comment: You were right, after adding the path it was sent across all requests. The location block is called when I access an image file but it redirects me if I am not logged or if I am logged. Now in the browser the cookie when I try to access an image it has "nametest:test" (name:value) but it still redirects me to login. So I think that the comparison is wrong or I am missing something. Any idea?

Comment: Usually HTTP 301 redirects are cached by the browser so if you access that location as non-logged user first, next time you will be redirected no matter if you are logged or not. Clear the browser cache and change you redirect to HTTP 302. Try from the incognito window first.

Comment: Good to hear, but I still suggest to try implementing the `X-Accel-Redirect` solution, it seems far more elegant as for me.